# Null point Text message

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm working on coding an app that will allow a user to text someone on the fly with a pre written text saying they will be late getting home.

Just a minor for the fun of it app that could be useful to the kids who's parents are OCD about where the kids are and when.

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(constants.num, null, "hello world - From EMTxt", null, null);
        }
    });
```

Stacktrace:

```
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:369)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:87)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at lionsimages.com.emtxt.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-05 14:36:25.821: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is an NPE showing up on the sms.sendTextETC line

My guess would be for the constant.num. However I know the number itself is saved just fun and this only stops working when I press the button to send the text.

Any ideas whats wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Didn't you try to log the values of the different variables, just to find out which one is null ??

Comment: Sorry for  taking so long to get back ended up busy most of the day, posting here in a second.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Logcat as requested.

Comment: I am still not sure why you did not tried adding `Log.d(TAG, "num: " + constants.num);` to see if the only variable you pass is not the (almost obviously) the culprit.

Comment: is it valid to use  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault() from inside the inner class? are you sure that sms!=null?

Comment: Same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674890/smsmanager-null-pointer-exception & no answer. :(

Comment: It shocks me that is still active.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I done it:

1.Permission inside manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

2.On send button click

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SmsManager smsman=SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsman.sendTextMessage("+919037934301", null, "this is sms content", null, null);
}
```

In your case, i doubt on **constants.num**. Make sure,

1.`constants` is not null

2.`constants.num` is not null and is a valid `String`