# SmsManager Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am trying to send a text message using **smsManager** from a `BroadCast Receiver`.I am getting this error says `NullPointerException`. I do not know what is wrong with this. I am sick of this error. 
here is my code segment

```
GPSTracker tracker = new GPSTracker(context);
            MyLocation temp = tracker.getCurrentLocation();
            String message = sp.getString("auto_text", "") + "\n"
                    + "Latitude: "+temp.getLatitude() + "\nLogitude: "+temp.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress(),
                    null, message, null, null);
```

String message is not null. it is displayed in toast .
If I Replace message with

```
sp.getString("auto_text","")+" "+temp.getLatitude()+" "+temp.getLongitude();
```

then it is working fine.

MyLocation.java

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MyLocation implements Parcelable{

    double latitude,longitude;
    public MyLocation() {
    }
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getLatitude()+" , "+getLongitude();
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeDouble(latitude);
        dest.writeDouble(longitude);

    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyLocation> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyLocation>() {
        public MyLocation createFromParcel(Parcel pc) {
            return new MyLocation(pc);
        }

        public MyLocation[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyLocation[size];
        }
    };
    public MyLocation(Parcel pc){
        latitude = pc.readDouble();
        longitude  = pc.readDouble();

    }

}
```

LogCat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.blogspot.uappmarket.locationbasedproject.Receiver.InCommingSmsReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:369)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:87)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at com.blogspot.uappmarket.locationbasedproject.Receiver.InCommingSmsReceiver.onReceive(InCommingSmsReceiver.java:33)
02-03 08:54:22.822: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
```

Comment: Do you understand what a NullPointerException is?  Do you know how to read logcat?  You you know how to use the debugger?  Please let us know so that we can give the right level of help.

Comment: post full code of InCommingSmsReceiver class and put a check for `smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress()` is null or not

Comment: @Simon I know NullPointerException. My message String is not null. it is working fine when i print it on the log.

Comment: `smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress()` is not null.And This is my OnReceive() Method.

Comment: Same issue & no answer for it on SO. :( It was working fine last day and now the same code is giving this issue. Unknown reason.

Comment: @Harpreet i think the method do not take weired text:-D i mean when i try `\n` and stuff to format things up then it is not working and when i just put plain text it works. i dont know it is answer or not.

Comment: @UsmanRiaz `\n` is permitted to work in SMS. I tried it and it works. Have you check my below answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a valid reason for this problem. 
That is : `SmsManager.sendTextMessage() throws NullPointerException` when SMS message is over size limit. i.e. max character limit is 159.

Comment: I had the same issue, and realized this was my issue as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Harpreet is right, in fact I ran into this situation just now.

you can just use the method [SmsManager.divideMessage(String text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#divideMessage%28java.lang.String%29) to let the system handle the length.

Answer (score 0):

The SmsManager.sendTextMessage() method also throws a NPE in the case that an invalid number is passed in as the destination. I found this out first hand when I was passing in a formatted phone number (e.g. "+1 999 999 9999"). The method did not throw a NPE when I stripped out the empty chars and removed the "+" before the country code.

Answer (score 0):

@harpreet aswer pointed me to the source of the error.

Note that SMS message length limit may vary depending on you mobile network operator.

Then you have two solutions:

1 - To send a shorter message.

-or-

2 - Split them in several messages (This may cause extra cost)

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> dividedText = sms.divideMessage(message);
for (String shortMessage : dividedText) {
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,shortMessage,null,null);
    }
```